# Identify row or column addition or deletion in excel

Tags: excel, algorithm

I'm looking for a solution which can able to identify the any row or column addition or deletion in a excel file.

What I have thought of as of now by using the **LCS** i.e. *"Longest common sub-sequence"* algorithm I can find out the common sub-sequence between two versions of a excel file, but this method is not 100% correct.

***For e.g.***

**Excel version 1**

```
 1 2 4 5 9 3
 4 9 3 7 5 3
 8 2 7 9 3 8
 9 7 2 8 2 4
```

After update, I remove 1 row (2nd row) and added 1 row (at same place i.e. 2nd).

**Excel Version 2**

```
 1 2 4 5 9 3
 4 9 5 7 5 3
 8 2 7 9 3 8
 9 7 2 8 2 4
```

Added row is almost similar except 1 cell item. In this case LCS would not work as it most of the cell items would be similar and I can't able to identify row was removed first and a new row was added.

Comment: @SolarMike I have added an example here, hope this will clarify more what exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: Does tracking changes to the workbook fulfil your requirement?

Comment: @Jerry tracking changes is not applicable for my requirement as I need to compare two versions of a excel file stored in a place. I need to create an algorithm which compares the changes in two file without opening it.

Comment: is the value unique for each row ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ not necessary, values can be same also.

Comment: any luck on the tries ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposed "comparison" algo :

1. label each lines (row), in the original file + new file
2. (a) find equivalent lines & match them (b) mark it.
3. (a) find new lines (b) mark it.

---

Example execution :

Assuming both data is located in A1:F4 in each file. In both file add new columns that do [1].

```
In Sheet1 & Sheet2 : 

in H1 put =ROW()
in I1 put =A1&","&B1&","&C1&","&D1&","&E1&","&F1
in J1 put =H1&" - "&I1
```

drag all downwards.

So for [2] Use a third excel file (or new sheet), compare the "content" and the "content-rowNumber" column. Since I'm using Sheet1 as Original file & Sheet2 as the NewFile, my formulas is as per below.

```
In Sheet3 : 
    in B1 label "row number"
    in C1 label "content InOriginal"
    in D1 label "RomNum&content InOriginal"
    in E1 label "content NewFile"
    in F1 label "RomNum&content NewFile"
    in H1 label "content match"
    in I1 label "content & rowNumber match"

Then,

in B2 put "=Sheet1!H1"
in C2 put "=Sheet1!I1"
in D2 put "=Sheet1!J1"
in E2 put "=Sheet2!I1"
in F2 put "=Sheet2!J1"
in H2 put "=EXACT(C2,E2)"
in I2 put "=EXACT(D2,F2)"
```

and drag downwards.

the TRUE/FALSE result is the result of the (basic) comparison. Should you need to do more analysis, you may proceed to modify/add the needed formulas.

Hope it helps. ( :

The sample file is [here](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=05d648fe0a6b5442b96632b7c22232cbb&authkey=AYeN56Ss7AXMzKwInUXi_9I&e=7VD3hh).